# Sprockets require all files from a gem's folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

So I'm using the [jqPlot gem](https://github.com/eightbitraptor/jqplot-rails) in Rails, and in order to use plugins, I'm required to do a

```
//=require jqplot/plugins/plugin-name
```

for each plugin that I want to use. Given that there are currently ~30 plugins in jqPlot, as I use more and more plugins, my `application.js` manifest will get bloated up with all the plugin requires. As a result, I was wondering if there was a way to require the entire plugin folder with a single `require`, as that would be significantly cleaner.

I've tried `//=require_tree ./jqplot/plugins` and `//= require_tree ./jqplot/plugins/`, and replacing `require_tree` with `require_directory` and all I get is an `ArgumentError` that `require_tree/require_directory argument must be a directory`.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Sadly, no, I never did figure this out. Instead, I think I switched to the Google Charts gem instead (there are several, I can't quite remember which I used). I suspect the only solution to this would be to include an index file at the top level of the gem (submit a pull request/issue to get this done, for example) so that that index can be referenced to pull in all the plugins (reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)